# Нужен ли вызов Bitmap.recycle()

Tags: java, android, bitmap

Подскажите, пожалуйста, необходим ли вызов Bitmap.recycle() в таком случае:

```
Bitmap myBitmap;

while (isRunning) {
    if (myBitmap != null) {
        // нужен ли вызов recycle() ?
    }

    myBitmap = getNewBitmap(); // каждый раз новый Bitmap

    // операции с myBitmap без дальнейшего вызова recycle()
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот тут все описано:
https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/manage-memory.html

`recycle()` рекомендуется вызывать на `Android 2.3.3` и ниже.
Начиная с `Android 3.0` система сама умеет переиспользовать память уже ненужных изображений, но с некоторыми ограничениями.
И только с `Android 4.4` это работает полностью без ограничений.

Решать вам, но скорее всего нет в этом необходимости.